# Display image from success ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm trying to display image in HTML from MySql and PHP.

My ajax request

```
$.ajax({
    type : "POST",      
    url : "jsonajax.php",
    data : { id: id },
    success : function(data){
        alert(data);
        $('#dialog').dialog('open');
        $('#dialog').html('<img src='+ data + '" />');
    }
});
```

My jsonajax.php

```
$id = $_REQUEST['id'];
$sql = "SELECT img_url FROM table_name WHERE id = $id";
$res=$obj->_executeQuery($sql);
$res=$obj->getAll($res);
echo json_encode($res);
```

Now the `alert(data)` looks like

```
[{"img_url":"images\/Jellyfish.jpg"}]
```

I need to remove '\' and append the image src to display.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a datatype, like "Json"

Answer (score 0):

try

```
JSON.parse(data)
```

this will decode the data

Answer (score 0):

Add `dataType:"json"`

```
$.ajax({
  type : "POST",
  dataType: "json",      
  url : "jsonajax.php",
  data : { id: id },
  success : function(data){
      alert(data);
      $('#dialog').dialog('open');
      $('#dialog').html('<img src='+ data + '" />');
  } 
});
```

And then do `data.img_url`

Comment: This is not working. My response looks like this `[{"img_url":"images\/Jellyfish.jpg"}]`. I need to put value to img src.

Comment: Remove the backslash while adding it into src attribute. Imageurl=data.img_url;   data = Imageurl.replace(/\\"/g, '"');

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the string response to an object - which will automagically remove the slashes :)

Option 1: Parse the data with `JSON.parse(data)`

Option 2: You can specify the `dataType: 'json'` option in your `$.ajax` request.

```
 $.ajax({
    type : "POST",      
    url : "jsonajax.php",
    data : { id: id },
    dataType: 'json',  // This is what you're missing
    success : function(data){
        $('#dialog').html('<img src='+ data.image_url + '" />');
        $('#dialog').dialog('open');
    }
});
```

Checkout the dataType option on the docs: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

Make the ajax block like this (In your case):

```
$.ajax({
    type : "POST",      
    url : "jsonajax.php",
    data : { id: id },
    dataType: 'json',
    success : function(data){
        console.log(data);
        $('#dialog').dialog('open');
        $('#dialog').html('<img src=' + data[0].img_url + '" />');
    }
});
```

Hope this helps.

Note: Please do make sure that the image is located in the `images` folder from the the current Script.